# PIC32MX320F128H shadow set corruption for a function while interrupted

Tags: pic, interrupts

### Update 1

the problem vanished when I changed the way of context switching during interrupt from srs to soft

`#pragma interrupt InterruptHandler ipl1srs vector 0`

to

`#pragma interrupt InterruptHandler ipl1soft vector 0`

It's something related to shadow register set corruption, which I don't understand why ?

Any hints about the shadow register set and its corruption will be appreciated.

---

### Original question

The following code is for program (not completed yet ) that makes a stopwatch using interrupts on multiplexed 4 digit 7 segment display.

The unexpected behavior : parameter `n` in `delay` becomes larger than the passed value (`100`) although I decrements, and it gets stuck inside the loop.

I really can't think of anything on earth that make that possible while I use interrupts.

Used IDE: MPLAB X v4.01
Used Compiler: XC32 v1.44

```
// PIC32MX320F128H Configuration Bit Settings

// 'C' source line config statements

// DEVCFG3
// USERID = No Setting

// DEVCFG2
#pragma config FPLLIDIV = DIV_2        // PLL Input Divider (12x Divider)
#pragma config FPLLMUL = MUL_20         // PLL Multiplier (24x Multiplier)
#pragma config FPLLODIV = DIV_1         // System PLL Output Clock Divider (PLL Divide by 1)

// DEVCFG1
#pragma config FNOSC = PRIPLL           // Oscillator Selection Bits (Primary Osc w/PLL (XT+,HS+,EC+PLL))
#pragma config FSOSCEN = OFF            // Secondary Oscillator Enable (Disabled)
#pragma config IESO = OFF               // Internal/External Switch Over (Disabled)
#pragma config POSCMOD = XT             // Primary Oscillator Configuration (XT osc mode)
#pragma config OSCIOFNC = OFF           // CLKO Output Signal Active on the OSCO Pin (Disabled)
#pragma config FPBDIV = DIV_8           // Peripheral Clock Divisor (Pb_Clk is Sys_Clk/1)
#pragma config FCKSM = CSDCMD           // Clock Switching and Monitor Selection (Clock Switch Disable, FSCM Disabled)
#pragma config WDTPS = PS1048576        // Watchdog Timer Postscaler (1:1048576)
#pragma config FWDTEN = OFF             // Watchdog Timer Enable (WDT Disabled (SWDTEN Bit Controls))

// DEVCFG0
#pragma config DEBUG = OFF              // Background Debugger Enable (Debugger is disabled)
#pragma config ICESEL = ICS_PGx2        // ICE/ICD Comm Channel Select (ICE EMUC2/EMUD2 pins shared with PGC2/PGD2)
#pragma config PWP = OFF                // Program Flash Write Protect (Disable)
#pragma config BWP = OFF                // Boot Flash Write Protect bit (Protection Disabled)
#pragma config CP = OFF                 // Code Protect (Protection Disabled)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#include <xc.h>
#include <plib.h>

#define A BIT_0
#define B BIT_1
#define C BIT_3
#define D BIT_6
#define E BIT_5
#define F BIT_2
#define G BIT_4

#define ZERO A|B|C|D|E|F
#define ONE B|C
#define TWO A|B|G|E|D
#define THREE A|B|C|D|G
#define FOUR B|C|F|G
#define FIVE A|C|D|F|G
#define SIX A|C|D|E|F|G
#define SEVEN A|B|C
#define EIGHT A|B|C|D|E|F|G
#define NINE A|B|C|D|F|G


#define DIGIT_0 BIT_0
#define DIGIT_1 BIT_1


volatile unsigned short counter = 0;
#pragma interrupt InterruptHandler ipl1srs vector 0

void InterruptHandler(void) {
    if (mT1GetIntFlag()) {

        counter= (counter+1)%10;
        mT1ClearIntFlag();
    }
}
void delay(unsigned int n ) {
    for(;n>0;n--)
    {
    int j = 0;
    while (j < 1000) {
        j++;
    }
    }
}

int outputnumber(unsigned short n,unsigned short digit) {


    mPORTDWrite(digit);
    if (n > 9)
        return -1;

    switch (n) {
        case 0:
            mPORTEWrite(ZERO);
            break;
        case 1:
            mPORTEWrite(ONE);
            break;
        case 2:
            mPORTEWrite(TWO);
            break;
        case 3:
            mPORTEWrite(THREE);
            break;
        case 4:
            mPORTEWrite(FOUR);
            break;
        case 5:
            mPORTEWrite(FIVE);
            break;
        case 6:
            mPORTEWrite(SIX);
            break;
        case 7:
            mPORTEWrite(SEVEN);
            break;
        case 8:
            mPORTEWrite(EIGHT);
            break;
        case 9:
            mPORTEWrite(NINE);
            break;


    }
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
        mPORTFSetPinsDigitalOut(0xFF);

    mPORTESetPinsDigitalOut(0x7F);
    mPORTDSetPinsDigitalOut(BIT_0 | BIT_1);

    OpenTimer1(T1_ON | T1_PS_1_256, 0x9897);
    INTEnableSystemSingleVectoredInt();

    mT1SetIntPriority(1);
    mT1IntEnable(1);
    while (1) {

        outputnumber(counter,DIGIT_0);
                        mPORTFToggleBits(0xFF);

        delay(100);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The data sheet says that the dedicated shadow registers are only available for the highest priority level. I guess trying to use them with a priority 1 interrupt *would* give unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: @RogerRowland, I used priority level 7 and the same result still happens, I noticed a strange behaviour . 
The local variables of `delay`  function don't get updated anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to allow the single vector to use shadow set register by adding the following to the setup code

```
INTCONbits.SS0 =1;
```

It's a not so clear in the documentation. -_-

It works with priority level 1 & 7 ( tested on both).